How to add the content of multiple columns in a sharepoint based on excel with a Http request
I am getting stuck with using http to create a list item in a specific list folder. I have used the following headers / body (see below), but it does not work. Can someone help me?
I am struggling anyway to change the code as such that I can add 5 columns from a table in a specific sharepoint list folder.

